# Replace word between two substrings (keeping other words)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace a word (e.g. `on`) if it falls between two substrings (e.g. `<temp>` & `</temp>`) however other words are present which need to be kept.

```
string = "<temp>The sale happened on February 22nd</temp>"
```

The desired string after the replace would be:

```
Result = <temp>The sale happened {replace} February 22nd</temp>
```

I've tried using regex, I've only been able to figure out how to replace everything lying between the two `<temp>` tags. (Because of the `.*?`)

```
result  = re.sub('<temp>.*?</temp>', '{replace}', string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

However `on` may appear later in the string not between `<temp></temp>` and I wouldn't want to replace this.

Comment: *it falls between two substrings* - which two substrings? Can you please provide an example of original string and replaced string?

Comment: Sadly there is no support for \G and \K in the re-module.

Comment: Youre desired output is not valid XML. You can't open the `<replace>` element and then close `</temp>`.

Comment: Its not meant to be XML, just indicators for myself for a later date

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea. Can you use a different replacement, for example `{replace}`?

Comment: Yes, that's fine (edited original post)

Comment: Is there just one `on` or all `on`s to replace? Use [`re.sub('<temp>(.*?)</temp>', lambda m: "<temp>{}</temp>".format( m.group(1).replace(" on ", " {replace} ") ), string, flags=re.DOTALL)`](https://ideone.com/GIJ8iA) if you want to replace all space+`on`+space with space+`{replace}`+space.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.sub('(<temp>.*?) on (.*?</temp>)', lambda x: x.group(1)+" <replace> "+x.group(2), string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Output:

```
<temp>The sale happened <replace> February 22nd</temp>
```

**Edit:**

Changed the regex based on suggestions by Wiktor and HolyDanna.

P.S: Wiktor's comment on the question provides a better solution.

Comment: The regex is not appropriate actually, the idea is right.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks. Can you please elaborate? If you suggest the right regex I will replace it or else if you are going to answer this question, then I will delete my answer based on yours.

Comment: This works, however is it possible to limit it just between <temp></temp>? Also replaces on if its outside the tags

Comment: See my suggestion to the question.

Comment: I think the right regex would be '(<temp>.*?)'+word+'(.*?</temp>)', as your regex will work whether or not there are 'temp' elements.

Comment: One or two remarks: this regex (`'(<temp>.*?)on(.*?</temp>)'`) will remove 1 `on` substring inside a `<temp>....</temp>` string, 2) the `on` will be removed like this - `<temp>The sale postponed on February 22nd</temp>` -> `<temp>The sale postp<replace>ed on February 22nd</temp>`. I guess you want `rr'(<temp>.*?) on (.*?</temp>)'` and replace with `x.group(1)+" <replace> "+x.group(2)`, 3) this does not account for nested `<temp>` tags.

Comment: This might fail, if there are multiple temp-constructs in a single line, with on between (but not inside one). I would also suggest using word boundaries around on.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html):

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("<temp>The sale happened on February 22nd</temp>")
root.text = root.text.replace(" on ", " {replace} ")
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

Output:

```
<temp>The sale happened {replace} February 22nd</temp>
```

Comment: I think you need to have code to find the `<temp` tags, since they are presumably part of some larger file.

Comment: `string` is valid XML. Let's take the question as it is written down and don't let us guess.